# Putting the CC2541 to sleep

Tags: bluetooth, sleep

I have a [bluetooth module](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1pcs-JDY-10-BLE-Bluetooth-4-0-Uart-Transparent-Transmission-Attachment-Compatible-with-CC2541-Bluetooth-Module/32883118874.html?spm=a2g0s.9042311.0.0.3f274c4d9oCE2y) which uses the [CC2541](http://www.ti.com/product/CC2541) IC. My project is battery powered and so i want to be able to put the device to sleep.i have been looking about trying to find how to do this and it would seem that there is no sleep/wake pin but one has to program the chip itself to put it to sleep. could anyone just confirm this before i start assembling a high side mosfet config. to power the module on/off please? thanks.

Comment: I worked on the CC2650 which is quite similar. These devices have a sleep mode with very low consumption, I don't see any reason not using it. you can wake from an external trigger like a button. Note the CC25XX can only be programmed with an expensive tool suite, while the CC26XX can be programmed with free tools. If you can use a CC26XX device it will make your life easier / cheaper.

Comment: i only have experience programming the atmega from the arduino IDE so i think figuring out how to program these chips may be a stretch for the time i have and so switching with a mosfet is still looking like the preferable option...

Answer (score 1):

How do you interface with this chip? It seems to have three power modes which you can configure:

- Power Mode 1 (4-µs Wake-Up): 270 µA
- Power Mode 2 (Sleep Timer On): 1 µA
- Power Mode 3 (External Interrupts): 0.5 µA

Maybe this user guide may help you:
http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/swru191d/swru191d.pdf